# HUE got hanged while running Hive Query with WHERE clause

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I am facing problem in running `Hive` query in `Hue` with `WHERE` clause. `Hue` got hanged and after some time getting `Time Out` error message. Below are the queries and results:

```
select loc,class from test_ods.data_ods_covg where loc='C2362-80D9-0050'; (Hue got hanged and then timeout error coming)  

select loc,class from test_ods.data_ods_covg; (running successfully)  

select count(*) from test_ods.data_ods_covg; (running successfully).
```

Could you please anybody help me to understand why `Hive` query is hanged with `WHERE` clause. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any hints in the HiveServer2 logs? If it timeouts it means a call to HiveServer2 gets stuck (execute statement, fetch status...)

Comment: Thanks for reply....I have fixed this issue...problem was SELECT query has WHERE clause on a field and that field is not a partiton field in the table. Added the partition on that field and problem resolved.